# import matplotlib fails with DLL load error but only in spyder

Tags: matplotlib, virtualenv, python-import, spyder

I am using miniconda. Spyder is installed in the base environment and configured with spyder_kernels to point to the interpreter in my work environment called py37. That is where numpy, pandas and matplotlib are installed.

When I activate py37 in a command prompt and use python there I can use matplotlib in my scripts without incident.

When I attempt to run the same scripts from spyder, I get this DLL import error:

```
File "C:\Users\eli\miniconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 190, in _check_versions
        from . import ft2font

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Can someone tell me how to diagnose this issue further? It seems like it is trying to import from the correct environment. `import numpy` and `import pandas` do work (both are only installed in py37, not base). Is this some sort of interference from the base environment? I'm aware I could install spyder in the py37 environment, but I like the spyder-kernels idea because it would keep the working environment simpler ... if I can get it to work.

Comment: The tag should be `matplotlib`, not `numpy`, right? Now, if I remember correctly, I had a similar issue with the `ft2font` import (the referred `dll` respectively). I'm not 100% sure but I think installing `matplotlib` from [Christoph Gohlke's whl files](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib) solved the issue for me since this is related to some OS-specific `dlls` (works-on-Linux-not-on-Windows kind of thing). I must say though that I'm not using `conda`/`miniconda` so I can't tell if that will work for you.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this issue requires an upgrade on the Spyder and Spyder-kernel side and/or an environmental variable be set on the Windows side.

On the Spyder side, there is an improvement in the release candidate version (4.0.0rc2) with the most up-to-date python and spyder-kernels > 1.8. These had to be installed from the spyder-ide channel.

Then for me it still didn't work because an old DLL search path issue. I had to set this environmental variable which takes one system directory out of the search path for Anaconda:

```
CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE to 1
```

On my system, I think it might have been interesting to try only this latter change.

My gratitude to the spyder developers. This took several iterations.